# Payment methods not showing if cart total is 0 in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, payment-method

I'm setting up a store for a client with multiples user roles. One of them need to have prices of 0$ because the company's billed monthly. Others roles have to pay differents prices with multipliers depending on their roles using "Product Price by User Role".

**Anyway, when a user buy some products for 0$ the COD method's not showing** and i need that payment gateway to set a custom status.

**Anyone encountered the problem before?** If so, any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Anyone encountered the problem before?"*. **This is default behavior in WooCommerce**

To prevent this, use:

```php
// Looks at the totals to see if payment is actually required.
function filter_woocommerce_cart_needs_payment( $needs_payment, $cart ) {
    // Set true
    $needs_payment = true;
    
    return $needs_payment;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 10, 2 );
```

Or in short

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', '__return_true' );
```

AND

```php
// Checks if an order needs payment, based on status and order total.
function filter_woocommerce_order_needs_payment( $needs_payment, $order, $valid_order_statuses ) {  
    // Set true
    $needs_payment = true;

    return $needs_payment;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_payment', 'filter_woocommerce_order_needs_payment', 10, 3 );
```

Or in short

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_payment', '__return_true' );
```